# character decoding failed error

Tags: html, struts2

I'm unable to understand why there occurs character decoding failed warning at my server.

> May 19, 2012 2:56:57 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters
>
> WARNING: Parameters: Character decoding failed. Parameter 'width' with value '100%' has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.

Comment: Some context would be helpful. I'd guess because of the `%`, but we really have no idea when the error happens, what's happening when it occurs, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the % at the end signifies a bad encoding. If properly encoded, it should really be followed by two hexadecimal characters.

Comment: There is a parameter `with`, which value is `100%`. This should be url-encoded like this somehow `width=100%25` because `%25` is the code for %. Check the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

if 'Parameters: Character decoding failed' warning include % issue then we can use given below 
code, no need to do any thing. I am using this in my ajax function.

```
var productPromoCodeIdParam = productPromoCodeId.replace('%','%25');
```